# An opencv function similar to matlab's graythresh

Tags: matlab, opencv

Hi i'm trying to convert a matlab code to opencv code. So I need something that does what `graythesh` in matlab does and give me a proper threshold for my grayscale image. Has this been already implemented in opencv cause I couldn't find it.

Thank you

Comment: OpenCV Threshold functions are described here : [Basic Thresholding Operations](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

Comment: These are thresholding functions and I already knew about them. What I wanted was a function that calculates a good threshold. Of course using otsu's thresholding method.

Comment: there is a type THRESH_OTSU for threshold function [link here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-threshold). Otherwise, there are several implementations ([here](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Otsu-thresholding-td3491712.html) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953993/otsu-thresholding-for-depth-image) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @georgesl mentioned, combine `THRESH_OTSU` with other types, for example:

```
threshold ( grey_image, bin_image, 0, 255, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Opencv. In order to do so, the cv.threshold() function is used, where cv.THRESH_OTSU is passed as an extra flag. The threshold value can be chosen arbitrary. The algorithm then finds the optimal threshold value which is returned as the first output.

```
import cv2 as cv
ret2,th2 = cv.threshold(img,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
#th2 is the thresholded image
```

Source: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html