# Mask Image region for Otsu Threshold with OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I have images were certain regions are set to 255 to not interfere with the region of interest. When doing an Otsu threshold, these regions offset the threshold value.

[image: Image with whited-out areas that throw off the Otsu threshold]

I found a good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953993/otsu-thresholding-for-depth-image) how to do this but my python implementation is slow. Given that I rountinly run my script on 10'000 images, more speed would save me days.

Here an example of what I'm doing

```
        from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
        #import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import numpy as np
        import cv2

        #Using the image provided in the question
        img = cv2.imread('imgSubbed-15.jpg', 0)

        yImg,xImg = img.shape
        how_many_255 = len(np.where(img==255)[0])
        tempThresImg = np.zeros((1,yImg * xImg - how_many_255), np.uint8)

        count=0
        for ii in range(xImg):
            for jj in range(yImg):
                if img[jj, ii] != 255:
                   tempThresImg[0, count] =  img[jj, ii]
                   count +=1

        threshold, temp = cv2.threshold(tempThresImg,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) #using otsu threshold
        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,threshold,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        threshold1, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) #using otsu threshold

        cv2.imshow('Standard Way', thresh1)
        cv2.imshow('Removed 255s', thresh)
        print('\n\nThreshold with Removal= %d \t Standard Threshold = %d \n\n' %(threshold, threshold1))
```

The thresholds are 226 versus 250.

Could anyone recommend a way to speed this up?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33069436/5008845). It's C++, but it can be a useful reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the answer Miki linked, I realized that one can index with conditions in Python. The explicit loop takes a second, the indexing is miliseconds.

```
     tempThresImg = img[img !=  255]
```

Comment: I'vw found that this modifies the original structure of the matrix. Is there a way to leave their pixels in their original position?

Comment: Use numpy.where, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046162/numpy-array-loss-of-dimension-when-masking)